# Load SharePoint Assembly in powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I can load System.Windows.Forms using below line :

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
$openFile = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
```

But not able to load SharePoint assemblies using the similar line script:

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing") | Out-Null

$obj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Design
```

Getting below error:

> New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Design]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded`.

Am I doing any mistake. Same with Add-Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to create an instance of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Design` but according to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.design.aspx), that is a namespace, not a class. You should pass a class to `New-Object`. Choose one of the classes from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.design.aspx) if you wanted to create something from the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Design` namespace or choose from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.aspx) if you wanted to create something from the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing` namespace.